# Combine nested fields in scripted field

Tags: nested, elasticsearch-painless, kibana-6

I would like to create a scripted field that checks two properties of a nested field.

I have an ES index that contains information about processes. A process is configured as a **nested object**. Each *doc* can have more than one process. It is also possible to have more than one process of the same kind (same *processDefinitionKey*).

This is how the processes are structured at the moment:

```
"process" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "include_in_parent" : true,
  "properties" : {
    "created" : {
      "type" : "date",
      "format" : "date_optional_time"
    },
    "ended" : {
      "type" : "date",
      "format" : "date_optional_time"
    },
    "id" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "index" : false
    },
    "processDefinitionKey" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "processDefinitionName" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "raw" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : "case_insensitive_sort"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am interested in all active processes of a specific kind. So they must have a specific `processDefinitionKey` and must *not* have an `ended` property yet. I've written an ES query for it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "process",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "process.processDefinitionKey": "service_agreement"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "process.ended"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added this query as a filter that I can use on the Kibana dashboards. I think it works as it should.

However, I would prefer to add this property "has an active process of this kind" as a column in a search table by creating a **scripted field** for it. This is the scripted field I have come up with so far (in Painless):

```
doc['process.processDefinitionKey'].contains('service_agreement') && doc['process.ended'].empty
```

But the results here do not align with the query above. I am afraid that this script checks whether there is *a* process with the correct `processDefinitionKey` and *a* process without the `ended` property. But it does not check whether both properties are true for the same process.

How can I make sure the scripted field checks both the `processDefinitionKey` and the `ended` property of the same process?

I use Kibana 6.4.2

**EDIT:**

Example of a document where the scripted field should return `true` (the service_agreement process has not ended yet, the other process has):

```
{
  "_index": ...,
  "_type"...,
  "_id": ...,
  "_version": ...,
  "_score": ...,
  "_source": {
    "type": ...,
    ...,
    "process": [
      {
        "id": "130707",
        "created": "2017-09-11T09:50:52.000+02:00",
        "ended": "2017-09-13T10:16:43.000+02:00",
        "processDefinitionKey": "so_ondertekenproces",
        "processDefinitionName": "Samenwerkingsovereenkomst",
        "incidents": []
      },
      {
        "id": "c2a83c07-15f7-11e7-a20e-0242ac120004",
        "created": "2017-03-31T11:52:32.000+02:00",
        "processDefinitionKey": "service_agreement",
        "processDefinitionName": "Service Agreement",
        "incidents": []
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "process.created": [
      "2017-03-31T09:52:32.000Z",
      "2017-09-11T07:50:52.000Z"
    ],
    "process.ended": [
      "2017-09-13T08:16:43.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Example of a document where the scripted field should return `false`:

```
{
  "_index": ...,
  "_type": ...,
  "_id": ...,
  "_score": ...,
  "_source": {
    "type": ...,
    ...,
    "process": [
      {
        "id": "17154",
        "created": "2017-05-24T13:21:40.000+02:00",
        "ended": "2017-05-24T13:23:24.000+02:00",
        "processDefinitionKey": "so_ondertekenproces",
        "processDefinitionName": "Samenwerkingsovereenkomst",
        "incidents": []
      },
      {
        "id": "17263",
        "created": "2017-05-24T13:23:29.000+02:00",
        "ended": "2017-09-27T14:31:00.000+02:00",
        "processDefinitionKey": "so_ondertekenproces",
        "processDefinitionName": "Samenwerkingsovereenkomst",
        "incidents": []
      },
      {
        "id": "f1cd056e-15f7-11e7-a20e-0242ac120004",
        "created": "2017-03-31T11:53:51.000+02:00",
        "ended": "2017-10-10T11:35:47.000+02:00",
        "processDefinitionKey": "service_agreement",
        "processDefinitionName": "Service Agreement",
        "incidents": []
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "process.created": [
      "2017-03-31T09:53:51.000Z",
      "2017-05-24T11:21:40.000Z",
      "2017-05-24T11:23:29.000Z"
    ],
    "process.ended": [
      "2017-05-24T11:23:24.000Z",
      "2017-09-27T12:31:00.000Z",
      "2017-10-10T09:35:47.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are dealing with nested documents. So you need to iterate over the nested docs and evaluate if the required condition is a match or not. This can be achieved using the following script:

**UPDATED Answer:**

```
boolean res = false;
for(int i = 0; i < params['_source']['process'].length; i++) {
   if(params['_source']['process'][i]['processDefinitionKey'] == 'service_agreement' && !params['_source']['process'][i].containsKey('ended')) {
      res = true;
      break;
   }
}
return res;
```

Script in single line:

```
boolean res = false; for(int i = 0; i < params['_source']['process'].length; i++){ if(params['_source']['process'][i]['processDefinitionKey'] == 'service_agreement' && !params['_source']['process'][i].containsKey('ended')) { res = true; break; }} return res;
```

The scripted field will be of `boolean` type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @NishantSaini for your response! Due to the holiday time, I was not able to test this earlier. I'm sorry to say this does not return the desired output :( If I run `params._source.process` I get an array of processes. But I don't seem to be able to iterate over it (even `params._source.process.length` gives me nothing). I do not get any errors, so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @NeleR Its been a long time and I guess I have deleted my sample data as well. Will re-look and let you know.

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: This time I have tested with the sample data that you provided. It's working fine for me

Comment: Still not iterating over array??

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant, you beautiful thing!! I had been trying to do something *very* similar for hours, and I kept getting errors because I was trying to access the fields with `doc['field']`. Changing to `params['_source']` did it for me. Nowhere in the awful ES documentation I have found that nested fields can't be accessed with `doc`. THANK YOU